# Средство реализации полезной задумки.

Tags: php, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Всем привет. Небольшая команда энтузиастов хочет реализовать некий социальный сервис регионального масштаба с возможностью выхода на российский рынок. У нас возникли разногласия с выбором инструмента: битрикс или ruby on rails. Возможно вы сможете привести аргументы в пользу того или иного решения или предложить свой вариант.

Comment: Выбирайте то, с чем у вас больше опыта.

Answer (score 8):

Я знаю что это грубовато, но: нахер битрикс. С ним вы ещё натерпитесь.

1. Во-первых, PHP. Это плохой инструмент для сложных проектов.
2. Во-вторых, платная поддержка.

Плюсы в пользу Rails:

1. Сообщество профессионалов. Наверное голословное утверждение, но я считаю что среди рельсовиков профессионалов больше чем среди битрикс-программистов.
2. Сложившаяся культура тестирования всего и вся.
3. Внимательное отношение к легаси-коду, гибкое управление зависимостями. Запустить сегодня проект на старых рубях и старых рельсах -- не проблема.
4. Преимущества языка Ruby, большая гибкость и выразительность. Меньше всякой тупой херни как в PHP.

Comment: @Vladimir VG, Радует пункт №4 после [этого](www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXEgk1Hdze0) видео ;)

Comment: > @Vladimir VG, Радует пункт №4 после этого видео ;)

По количеству WAT-ов PHP лихо обгоняет JavaScript с Ruby на целую милю. Кто-кто, а PHP по некосистентности среди языко программирования лидер.